# Python Requests can't download file

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

My Code:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent


ua = UserAgent()

headers = {'Connection': 'keep-alive','User-Agent': str(ua.chrome)}

data = {'inUserName': 'username', 'inUserPass': 'password'}
    
site_url = 'https://www.website.com/home/welcome'

s = requests.Session()
r = s.post(site_url,data=data,headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
        r = s.get("https://www.website.com/text/2017?y=2021&x=xls", allow_redirects=True, headers=headers,cookies=r.cookies)
       
        output = open('file.xls', 'wb')
        output.write(r.content)
        output.close()
```

Ihn I log into the website to download a xls file i just get th ethyl code of the welcome site in the file. When I open the site in my browser and have a active session the code works perfectly.
Does anybody know what to do?

Thanks

Comment: they'll probably write some cookies after your post.  These need to be included in the headers of your next request if the download needs authorization.  (or just use Selenium and make sure you give time for the browser to write the cookies...)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this download code

```
def download_image_from_url(image_url, path):
    img_data = requests.get(image_url).content

    with open(path, 'wb') as handler:
        handler.write(img_data)
```

Comment: The download works fine if I copy the cookies from the browser. But py-requests can't generate/regenerate these cookies to